# How can I blit 8bpp paletted (Indexed8) graphics HW-accelerated in WP8.1/WinRT/XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, gpu

I'm porting an old DOS game to WP8.1. The DOS game rendered all it's graphics in VGA, which is an 8 bit per pixel graphics mode. A palette maps each of the 256 colors to a specific RGB-triple. Right now I'm manually converting all pixels per frame (60 FPS) via look up table to 32bpp (RGBA), because `WriteableBitmap` only accepts images in this format.

**What is the best way to blit indexed/paletted 8bpp images at 60 FPS, hardware-accelerated on Windows Phone 8.1/WinRT/XAML?**

Software conversion to RGBA costs too much CPU time on a phone. Ideally I'd like to stay away from DX if possible, because that'd presumably be a lot of work and because D3DFMT_P8 is not supported on WP anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 8 BPP image file data in a memory stream, then load images from that stream. Both BMP, GIF and PNG formats [are supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff462087(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_ImageSupport) on the platform, I think BMP will be the easiest for you to implement. To reduce memory manager stress, reuse the memory stream across frames, just overwrite the image data with the new one.

However, I’m not sure this will solve your performance problem.
The right way to do what you want is DirectX. It doesn't matter D3DFMT_P8 is not supported, you can use D3DFMT_I8, and in pixel shader apply any palette you like (you could e.g. lookup from the second 256x1 RGB texture containing the palette).
Take a look at “Direct3D and XAML App (Windows Phone)” project template, it's not that complex and even contains a pixel shader you can change to do those texture lookups.

**Update:** I’m glad the simpler solution worked for you.
Now remember all WP8 devices are at least dual core. So if you want to improve your frame rate, you can use 2 instances of MemoryStream. Run your game loop in a background thread, to write a frame data into one MS. At the same time, in the GUI thread, load and display the image from the second MemoryStream. When both tasks are finished, just swap the pointers of the MemoryStream instances, and repeat. If presentation takes the time comparable with your game loop, you may get up to 50% FPS improvement.

Comment: It seems that my question was unclear: I'm doing the conversion in real-time, per frame, at 60 FPS. I updated the question to make this clearer. Or do you think your solution should be applicable to animations somehow? - I will have a look at the project template.

Comment: Sure it applies. Don't write anything to flash memory. Create a MemoryStream object containing 256-colors BMP image with palette, then 60 times per second ( update MemoryStream overwriting image data, load image from the stream )

Comment: Works surprisingly well. And even more surprising: Low GC pressure... Sometimes I underestimate WPF.

Comment: Good. See the update. It's however not WPF, it's Silverlight. Or just XAML/WinRT.